# How to convert repated rows data to columns in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have a data frame `df1` where  column `name` names repeat after every 3 rows. I need to convert them to a single row.
This is how `df` looks

```
name   marks
john   63
mark   45
pieter 32
beth   02

john   25
mark   01
pieter 23
beth   42

john   03
mark   43
pieter 42
beth   23
```

I need the output in the following format

```
type  john mark pieter beth 
marks 63   45   32     02
marks 25   01   23     42
marks 03   43   42     23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```py
df=df.assign(id=df.groupby("name").cumcount()) \
    .pivot(columns="name", index="id") \
    .stack(level=0).reset_index(level=1) \
    .rename(columns={"level_1": "type"})

del df.index.name
del df.columns.name
```

Outputs:

```py
    type beth john mark pieter
0  marks   02   63   45     32
1  marks   42   25   01     23
2  marks   23   03   43     42
```

Comment: Thanks, I tweaked my answer!

Comment: Yeah its working, But I don't want colums `name id`. How to drop this now?

Comment: this is my answer with an unnecessary `DataFrame.assign`, -1

Comment: @ansev  not really - I kind of got from different approach originally, and after to accommodate potential different metrics - it's slightly different, but doing exactly the same logic, because how would you expect to do it differently really? `assign` is unnecessary as long as you do the same other way around, however I don't see how your approach is better than mine...

Comment: we can do it without assigning (see my answer). This reduces the number of methods and is therefore more efficient.Also, his initial answer was wrong, because as I already told you, you only considered one column. So I consider this answer a copy. 
A copy that has been accepted and voted (which I do not understand).

Comment: @Raghu - I added 2 lines to my answer, now it should do the trick for you

Comment: @ansev - I'd disagree on both, but please maybe flag my answer to the moderator's attention - don't think making any kind of argument about it in here makes sense

Comment: I simply had to correct this answer, in doing so it became practically mine. At the end this has been accepted. I think it is almost a copy, therefore I do not understand that you kept the answer and much less that it is accepted and voted

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
new_df = (df.pivot_table(index=df.groupby('name').cumcount(), columns='name')
            .rename_axis(columns=['type',None])
            .stack(level=0)
            .reset_index(level=1))
print(new_df)
    type  beth  john  mark  pieter
0  marks     2    63    45      32
1  marks    42    25     1      23
2  marks    23     3    43      42
```

or

```
new_df = (df.assign(index=df.groupby('name').cumcount())
            .melt(['index','name'], var_name='type')
            .pivot_table(index=['type','index'], columns='name',values = 'value')
            .reset_index('type'))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative :

```
res = (df
       .pivot(columns='name',values='marks')
       .bfill()
       #remove repititions on the beth column
       #this impacts the other columns as well
       .drop_duplicates('beth')
       .rename_axis(columns=None)
       .astype(int)
       .assign(type='marks')
        #adjust column positions to match ur output
       .reindex(['type','john','mark','pieter','beth'],axis=1)
       .reset_index(drop=True)
      )

res
    type    john    mark    pieter  beth
0   marks   63      45      32      2
1   marks   25      1       23      42
2   marks   3       43      42      23
```

You could also step out of Pandas into numpy, using the [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) method and at the end, create a new dataframe :

```
name_len = df.name.nunique()
names = df.name.unique()
df_len = len(df) 
reshape_tuple = (df_len//name_len,name_len)
reshaped = df.marks.to_numpy().reshape(reshape_tuple)
#create new dataframe
res = pd.DataFrame(reshaped, columns = names)
#insert the 'type' column at the beginning of the dataframe
res.insert(0,'type','marks')

print(res)


    type    john    mark    pieter  beth
0   marks   63      45        32    2
1   marks   25      1         23    42
2   marks   3       43        42    23
```